# I am trying to print the dynamic value using react but it wont work for me

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import { Math } from "core-js";

const Person = () => {
  return (
    <p>
      Hello my name chetan and i am {Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)} year old
    </p>
  );
};

export default Person;
```

Please refer the above code. I have been trying to display dynamic value but I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: core_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Math.random is not a function
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need `import { Math } from 'core-js';`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import package core.js, You can use the Default Math function of javascript like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Person = () => {
  return (
    <p>
      Hello my name chetan and i am {Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)} year old
    </p>
  );
};

export default Person;
```